# Conway's Game Of Life using SFML and MVC

Tags: c++, mvc, game-of-life, sfml

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193547/simple-implementation-of-conways-game-of-life-with-sfml).
I followed the given advice and implemented the [MVC design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC_Design_Pattern). As I've never used MVC before I am quite unsure about the quality or if it is even considered a "valid" MVC implementation.
The design is (I believe) quite straight-forward. *Main* acts as the user interacting with the *controller*. *Controller* updates the *model* which in turn updates the *view*. Despite my doubts it actually runs better than before. I haven't profiled anything but the earlier version would burn a lot of cycles doing nothing but displaying the state while now there is barely any usage even when the simulation is running.
I'm mainly wondering if more things from *main* should be moved into other parts or if this is fine as is? Any other observations are welcome as well of course.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "controller.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    constexpr int width = 1440;
    constexpr int height = 900;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "0",
                            sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    GameOfLife::Controller controller{width, height, window};

    constexpr float update_delay = .5;
    sf::Clock clock;
    clock.restart();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;

                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    controller.on_keypress(event);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();

        if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= update_delay) {
            controller.update_model();
            clock.restart();
        }

        controller.display_view();

        window.display();
    }
}
```

**controller.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "model.h"
#include "view.h"

#include <SFML/System.hpp>

namespace GameOfLife {

class Controller {
public:
    Controller(int const width, int const height, sf::RenderWindow& win);

    void update_model();
    void display_view();
    void on_keypress(sf::Event const& event);

private:
    View view;
    Model model;
    bool is_active = false;
};

}
```

**controller.cpp**

```
#include "controller.h"
#include "model.h"
#include "view.h"

#include <SFML/System.hpp>

namespace GameOfLife {

Controller::Controller(int const width, int const height, sf::RenderWindow& win)
    : view{width, height, win}
    , model{width, height, view}
{}

void Controller::update_model() {
    if (is_active) {
        model.update();
    }
}

void Controller::display_view() {
    view.display();
}

void Controller::on_keypress(sf::Event const& event) {
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::P) {
        is_active = !is_active;
    }

    if (!is_active && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::U) {
        model.update();
    }

    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R) {
        model.reset();
    }
}

}
```

**model.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "view.h"

#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

namespace GameOfLife {

class Model {
public:
    Model(int const width_, int const height_, View& view_);

    void update();
    void reset();

private:
    void seed_grid();
    int count_neighbors(int const m_origin, int const n_origin) const;
    void check_rules(int const pos, int const neighbors);
    void apply_rules(int pos, bool const state);

    int width;
    int height;
    std::vector<bool> grid_current;
    std::vector<bool> grid_next;
    View& view;
    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uint64_t iterations = 0;
    static constexpr bool cell_alive = true;
    static constexpr bool cell_dead = false;
};

}
```

**model.cpp**

```
#include "model.h"
#include "view.h"

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

namespace GameOfLife {

Model::Model(int const width_, int const height_, View& view_)
    : width{width_}
    , height{height_}
    , grid_current{}
    , grid_next{}
    , view{view_}
    , rng{}
{
    std::random_device rd;
    rng.seed(rd());

    reset();
}

void Model::update() {
    grid_current.swap(grid_next);

    ++iterations;

    for (int m = 0; m < height; ++m) {
        for (int n = 0; n < width; ++n) {
            check_rules(width * m + n, count_neighbors(m, n));
        }
    }
}

void Model::reset() {
    grid_current.clear();
    grid_current.resize(static_cast<std::size_t>(width * height));
    grid_next.clear();
    grid_next.resize(static_cast<std::size_t>(width * height));
    seed_grid();
    iterations = 0;
}

void Model::seed_grid() {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> pos_dist(0, width * height);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> cells(width * height / 2,
                                            width * height);

    int initial_cell_nr = cells(rng);
    while (initial_cell_nr > 0) {
        std::size_t pos = pos_dist(rng);
        if (grid_next[pos] == cell_dead) {
            grid_next[pos] = cell_alive;
            --initial_cell_nr;
            view.update(pos, cell_alive, 0U);
        }
    }
}

int Model::count_neighbors(int const m_origin, int const n_origin) const {
    int neighbors = 0;
    for (int m_current = m_origin - 1; m_current <= m_origin + 1; ++m_current) {
        for (int n_current = n_origin - 1; n_current <= n_origin + 1; ++n_current) {
            if (m_current < 0 || m_current >= height ||
                n_current < 0 || n_current >= width) {
                continue;
            }

            if (m_current == m_origin && n_current == n_origin) {
                continue;
            }

            if (grid_current[width * m_current + n_current] == cell_alive) {
                if (++neighbors > 3) {
                    return neighbors;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}

void Model::check_rules(int const pos, int const neighbors) {
    apply_rules(pos, grid_current[pos]);

    // Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies,
    // as if caused by under population.
    if (grid_current[pos] == cell_alive && neighbors < 2) {
        apply_rules(pos, cell_dead);
    }

    // Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on
    if (grid_current[pos] == cell_alive && (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3)) {
        apply_rules(pos, cell_alive);
    }

    // Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies,
    // as if by overpopulation.
    if (grid_current[pos] == cell_alive && neighbors > 3) {
        apply_rules(pos, cell_dead);
    }

    // Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell,
    // as if by reproduction.
    if (grid_current[pos] == cell_dead && neighbors == 3) {
        apply_rules(pos, cell_alive);
    }
}

void Model::apply_rules(int pos, bool const state) {
    grid_next[pos] = state;

    view.update(pos, state, iterations);
}

}
```

**view.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <vector>

namespace GameOfLife {

class View {
public:
    View(int const width, int const height, sf::RenderWindow& win_);

    void update(int pos, bool const state, std::uint64_t const iterations_);
    void display();

private:
    std::vector<std::uint_fast8_t> pixmap;
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::RenderWindow& win;
    std::uint64_t iterations = 0;
    bool model_was_updated = false;
    static constexpr int offset_r = 0;
    static constexpr int offset_g = 1;
    static constexpr int offset_b = 2;
    static constexpr int offset_a = 3;
    static constexpr int rgba_quad = 4;
};

}
```

**view.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "view.h"

#include <string>

namespace GameOfLife  {

View::View(int const width_, int const height_, sf::RenderWindow& win_)
    : pixmap{std::vector<uint_fast8_t>(width_ * height_ * rgba_quad)}
    , texture{}
    , sprite{}
    , win{win_}
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width_ * height_ * rgba_quad; i += rgba_quad) {
        pixmap[i + offset_r] = 255;
        pixmap[i + offset_g] = 255;
        pixmap[i + offset_b] = 255;
        pixmap[i + offset_a] = 0;
    }

    texture.create(width_, height_);
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setPosition(0, 0);
}

void View::update(int pos, bool const state, std::uint64_t const iterations_) {
    pos *= rgba_quad;
    pos += offset_a;
    pixmap[pos] = state ? 255 : 0;
    iterations = iterations_;
    model_was_updated = true;
}

void View::display() {
    if (model_was_updated) {
        texture.update(&pixmap[0]);
        model_was_updated = false;
    }

    win.setTitle(std::to_string(iterations));
    win.draw(sprite);
}

}
```